# Redirecting stdout to Terminal AND a log .txt file with Python Subprocess.run()

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I am trying to run a command and redirect the output to a .txt file as well as be able to see it in terminal using `subprocess.run()`. I previously used `2>&1 | file.txt` to accomplish this but would like to mimic that flavor with subprocess.run() and `shell = False`

I am currently able to redirect `stdout` to a `.txt.` successfully but I would like to be able to see it in terminal as well. Is there a way to accomplish this? I am on `Python 3.6`

```
        with open(model_dest_dir + 'Deepspeech_progress.txt', 'w') as f:
             train_model = subprocess.run(train_cmds, shell = False, cwd = '/home/', env =  export_dict, stdout = f)
        #for stdout_line in iter(train_model.stdout.readline, b''):
        #    print(stdout_line)
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have a working solution albeit not with `subprocess.run()`. I had to use `Popen` like so:

```
# train the model and write logs to .txt file
with open(model_dest_dir + 'Deepspeech_progress.txt', 'w') as f:
    train_model_proc = subprocess.Popen(train_cmds, cwd = '//DeepSpeech/', env =  export_dict, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines = True)  
    for line in train_model_proc.stdout:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
        f.write(line)
train_model_proc.wait() # wait for Popen to finish
f.close()
```

Comment: `train_cmds='deepspeech --model C:/deepspeech/deepspeech-0.6.0-models/output_graph.pb --lm C:/deepspeech/deepspeech-0.6.0-models/lm.binary --trie C:/deepspeech/deepspeech-0.6.0-models/trie --audio C:/deepspeech/audio/8455-210777-0068.wav'
with open('C:/Deepspeech_progress.txt', 'w') as f: train_model_proc = subprocess.Popen(train_cmds, cwd = 'C:/', stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines = True)  
for line in train_model_proc.stdout:   sys.stdout.write(line)  f.write(line) train_model_proc.wait() f.close()` i tried this cmd but blank file is generated

Comment: can you please check this cmd